# Android: Deploying x86_64 package to x64 device generates incompatible ABI error

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio-2015, abi

I have created a brand new NativeActivity application using Visual Studio 2015 (Windows 10 64 bit). The native activity contains some example code which simply fades the screen between black/green. 
I can successfully deploy this to my test device using an x86 configuration. 
When I try to deploy using the x64 configuration I get 'Incompatible ABI' error.
To be specific:

> The package ABI 'x86_64' is incompatible with the ABI 'x64' of device
>   'Acer GT-810 (x64 - 549000410412)'

The error seems weird because surely x86_64 is x64?!

The device is definitely 64 bit.
Is it because this device does not actually have the ABI for x64?
Am I missing a compiler setting?

I have included the complete build output below:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Android1.NativeActivity, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
1>  ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Apps\apache-ant-1.9.3\
1>  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55
1>  NDK_ROOT=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r11c\
1>  Android1.NativeActivity.vcxproj -> C:\Dev\Android1\x64\Debug\libAndroid1.so
2>------ Build started: Project: Android1.Packaging, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>  ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
2>  ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Apps\apache-ant-1.9.3\
2>  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55
2>  java.home=
2>  NDK_ROOT=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r11c\
2>  ANDROID_NDK_HOME=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r11c\
2>  Buildfile: C:\Dev\Android1\Android1\Android1.Packaging\x64\Debug\Package\build.xml
2>
2>  -set-mode-check:
2>
2>  -set-debug-files:
2>
2>  -check-env:
2>   [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 25.1.7
2>   [checkenv] Installed at C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
2>
2>  -setup:
2>       [echo] Project Name: Android1.Packaging
2>    [gettype] Project Type: Application
2>
2>  -set-debug-mode:
2>
2>  -debug-obfuscation-check:
2>
2>  -pre-build:
2>
2>  -build-setup:
2>  [getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 24.0.1
2>       [echo] Resolving Build Target for Android1.Packaging...
2>  [gettarget] Project Target:   Android 5.1.1
2>  [gettarget] API level:        22
2>       [echo] ----------
2>       [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
2>       [echo] ----------
2>       [echo] Resolving Dependencies for Android1.Packaging...
2>  [dependency] Library dependencies:
2>  [dependency] No Libraries
2>  [dependency]
2>  [dependency] ------------------
2>       [echo] ----------
2>       [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
2>     [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on
2>
2>  -code-gen:
2>  [mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
2>  [mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
2>  [mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
2>       [echo] hasCode = false. Skipping aidl/renderscript/R.java
2>
2>  -pre-compile:
2>
2>  -compile:
2>       [echo] hasCode = false. Skipping...
2>
2>  -post-compile:
2>
2>  -obfuscate:
2>
2>  -dex:
2>       [echo] hasCode = false. Skipping...
2>
2>  -crunch:
2>     [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: C:\Dev\Android1\Android1\Android1.Packaging\x64\Debug\Package\res
2>     [crunch] To destination dir: C:\Dev\Android1\Android1\Android1.Packaging\x64\Debug\Package\bin\res
2>     [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache
2>
2>  -package-resources:
2>       [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
2>       [aapt] Creating full resource package...
2>
2>  -package:
2>  [apkbuilder] Found Deleted Target File
2>  [apkbuilder] Creating Android1.Packaging-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...
2>
2>  -post-package:
2>
2>  -do-debug:
2>   [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...
2>       [echo] Debug Package: C:\Dev\Android1\Android1\Android1.Packaging\x64\Debug\Android1.apk
2>  [propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Dev\Android1\Android1\Android1.Packaging\x64\Debug\Package\bin\build.prop
2>  [propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Dev\Android1\Android1\Android1.Packaging\x64\Debug\Package\bin\build.prop
2>  [propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Dev\Android1\Android1\Android1.Packaging\x64\Debug\Package\bin\build.prop
2>  [propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Dev\Android1\Android1\Android1.Packaging\x64\Debug\Package\bin\build.prop
2>
2>  -post-build:
2>
2>  debug:
2>
2>  BUILD SUCCESSFUL
2>  Total time: 1 second
3>------ Deploy started: Project: Android1.Packaging, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>Error installing the package. The package ABI 'x86_64' is incompatible with the ABI 'x64' of device 'Acer GT-810 (x64 - 549000410412)'.
3>Incompatible ABIs.
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```